How to integrate KeraCV MixUp & CuMix Augmentation into Image Data Generator?
I have the following lines of code that reads a csv file and prepares a data set to be fed into a tensorflow model using the Image Data Generator Class. This uses the subdirectory names as classes. How can I integrate KeraCV's CutMix and MixUp here?
    import pandas as pd
    from collections import defaultdict
    import os
    
    
    def find_duplicate_filenames(root_dir):
        files_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
            for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                files_dict[file].append(file_path)
        duplicates = {file: paths for file, paths in files_dict.items() if len(paths) > 1}
        return duplicates
    
    # Path to the directory with training images
    root_directory = 'train_images/'
    
    # Identifying duplicates
    duplicates_by_name = find_duplicate_filenames(root_directory)
    
    # Create a set of paths to exclude
    exclude_paths = {path for paths in duplicates_by_name.values() for path in paths}
    
    # Collect all valid image paths and their labels
    valid_files = []
    labels = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            if file_path not in exclude_paths:
                valid_files.append(file_path)
                labels.append(subdir.split('/')[-1])  # assuming folder names are class labels
    
    # Create DataFrame for the image paths and labels
    data = pd.DataFrame({'filename': valid_files, 'class': labels})
    
    
    data = data[data['class']!='']
    
    print(len(data['class'].unique()))

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

def custom_preprocessing(image):
    # Example of custom preprocessing logic
    # Adjust the image as required, this is just a placeholder
    image = np.clip(image, a_min=0, a_max=1)  # Ensuring the image is within the range [0, 1]
    return image

# ImageDataGenerator with custom preprocessing
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=custom_preprocessing,  # Using the custom preprocessing function
    width_shift_range=0.5,                         # Randomly shifts images horizontally
    horizontal_flip=False,                         # Randomly flips images horizontally
    vertical_flip=False                            # Randomly flips images vertically
)

# Continue with your model training setup


# Setup train and validation generators
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_data,
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='class',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical',    
    color_mode='rgb'
)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=valid_data,
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='class',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='rgb'
)

How can I add the KerasCV CutMix and MixUp layers here to add to the augmentation? I tried adding keras_cv.layers.CutMix() and keras_cv.layers.MixUp()into the model but it did not work. Thanks in advance!

@mhenning & @Innat Thank you for your help and suggestions. Diving into the documentation enabled me to come across the tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory function that takes in folder and subfolders of images. It uses the subfolder names as "classes". So I prepared my dataset the following way.
import numpy as np
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

from keras import layers

directory = "train_images"

IMG_SIZE = 224
# Load the dataset from the directory
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    label_mode='categorical',
    image_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    subset="both",  # Use 'training' or 'validation' as needed
)

AUTO = tf_data.AUTOTUNE
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_ds = dataset[0]  ## For training
def preprocess_image(image, label):
    image = tf_image.convert_image_dtype(image, "float32") / 255.0
    return image, label

train_ds = (
    train_ds
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .shuffle(1024)
    .map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
)



test_ds = dataset[1] #test set



test_ds = (
    test_ds.map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .prefetch(AUTO)
)


This snippet returns training and test data.
There is a KerasCV Tutorial that implements CutMix & mixUp that can be found here(https://keras.io/guides/keras_cv/cut_mix_mix_up_and_rand_augment/)
I used the code implemented there and integrated it to my project the following way
import keras_cv

cut_mix = keras_cv.layers.CutMix()
mix_up = keras_cv.layers.MixUp()



def cut_mix_and_mix_up(image, label):
    # Convert tuple to dictionary
    samples_dict = {'images': image, 'labels': label}
    
    # Apply CutMix
    mixed_samples = cut_mix(samples_dict)
    
    # Apply MixUp
    mixed_samples = mix_up(mixed_samples)
    
    # Convert dictionary back to tuple
    return (mixed_samples['images'], mixed_samples['labels'])




def preprocess(image, label):
    # Squeeze the unnecessary dimension out
    image = tf.squeeze(image, axis=[1])
    label = tf.squeeze(label,axis=[1])# Squeeze out the second dimension which is 1
    return image, label

# Apply the preprocessing function to training and testing datasets
train_ds = train_ds.map(preprocess)
test_ds = test_ds.map(preprocess)


train_ds = train_ds.map(cut_mix_and_mix_up, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


Plotting the first 8 samples of the first batch of images looks like the following way.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range(8):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image_batch[i])
    plt.show()
    plt.axis("off")
    




you might want to update tf.keras API to keras API (ref).

ImageDataGenerator is deprecated and you should switch to the workflow they showed here for augmentation and the tf.data.Dataset in general. You can read here why Datasets are really handy.
For augmentations, this makes it really simple. You can define a Sequential model, where you can add different augmentation layers:
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras_cv

augmentations = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.RandomTranslation(0, 0.5),
    keras.layers.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    keras_cv.layers.CutMix()
])

# example how to use in a net
real_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input([input_size]),
    augmentations,
    tf.keras.Dense(3)

While I'd normally not mix tf.keras and keras calls, here I mixed them even with keras_cv and it worked for a model. You can use these layers as first layes in your network like in the last code lines. They are only used on training data.

I see now that the CutMix layer needs both an image and segmentation mask as tuple input, while the other layers expect images only (or segmentation only, but not both as a tuple). In that case, you'd need a functional model where you augment images and segmentation mask separately, and merge them to a tuple for e.g. CutMix.
